# Redux action not present

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have set up correctly according to doc redux boilerplate. 
I have a folder of various action files which contains actions.
In this folder I have created an `index.js` where I am exporting all these files. I import it as named export. 
When I console log the function itself it is there, but when I console log out `this.props` its not present.
I have tried to console log out the function outside the class its `undefined`.

If I import the action directly from the file it is defined in it works.

**actions/formActions.js**

```
export const formInput = (key, val) => (
    {
        type: FORM_INPUT,
        payload: { key, val }
    }
);
```

**actions/index.js**

```
export * from './formActions';
```

**FormComp.js**

```
import { formInput } from './actions'; //  <-- this.props.formInput = undefined
```

or

```
import { formInput } from './actions/formActions'; //  <-- this.props.formInput = func
```

connect:

```
class InputField extends Component { ... }

const FormComp = connect(({ forms }) => ({ forms }), { formInput })(InputField);

export { FormComp };
```

**edit1:** If I inside `componentWillMount()` `console.log(formInput) //without this.props` its there.

**edit2 (solution?):**
I was able to map actions to props with `bindActionCreators`. How ever I don't understand why I need to use `bindActionCreators` and why I can't just export connect as it is with actions as second param.

```
const FormComp = connect(
  ({ forms }) => ({ forms }), 
  dispatch => bindActionCreators({ formInput }, dispatch)
)(InputField);
```

Comment: You missspelled formAction(s) ?

Comment: @TimH Sorry I have corrected the spelling in the examples.

Comment: FormComp.js is in the same directory of actions? Maybe try: import { formInput } from '../actions' or can you share your file tree?

Comment: @Ilario Yes its the same directory. Structure is same on both cases the only difference is the import string.

Comment: well, you're not dispatching!

Answer (score 0):

The reason `this.props.formInput` is not defined but `formInput` is defined is because the redux connect is not properly setting the function `formInput` against the variable(property) `formInput` within the component props.

1. `formInput` is the function you are importing,
2. `this.props.formInput` is the property that should "point" to the function you import.

Try (I have separated out for clarity)

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      forms: state.forms
    }
  }
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    formInput: (key, val) => dispatch(formInput(key val))
  };
}

export connect(
  mapStateToProps, 
  mapDispatchToProps
)(InputField);
```

Then anywhere in your code you call

```
this.props.formInput(key, val);
```

This will call the action via props, and therefore will dispatch. properly

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js#L18

Comment: Why would OP need to do it manually if `connect` already does it?

Answer (score -1):

You need to return a function which has `dispatch` and `getState` as parameter.

```
export const formInput = (key, val) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    // maybe additional stuff
    dispatch({
        type: FORM_INPUT,
        payload: { key, val }
    });
};
```

See title **Action Creators** from the documents: https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html

Comment: Why would OP need to do it? He neither dispatches multiple actions from the action creator nor uses current storage. Not to speak he/she would need thunk middleware to handle such an action creator.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko This is just a short example. We are talking about 10+ files in actions folder which together contain 60+ action creators. If I do `import actions from './actions' I can log out the whole structure.

Comment: @eden I Don't quite understand the difference here. Why I need to add dispatch to the action creator when I do `import { formInput } from './actions'` and why I don't need to include dispatch when importing directly from teh file where the action creator is defined in?

Comment: @parohy I was actually asking eden because I do think his solution wont help.

Comment: Since you're connecting your actions directly to your component, you need to  create a bound action creator that automatically dispatches. @YuryTarabanko Why don't you just try and see whether that works or not.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko plus, the reason you're not seeing `this.props.formInput` is either about binding `this` or connecting the component. Also you are able to see `console.log(formInput)` because you're importing that function, and it's available everywhere in the file.

Comment: @eden You could pass an object as `mapDispatchToProps` From docs "(Object or Function): If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props."

Comment: Please pay attention to docs better: `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {};
};`

Comment: I have cited the docs https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Comment: And on the other hand, see how he connects mapDispatchToProps: `const FormComp = connect(({ forms }) => ({ forms }), { formInput })(InputField);` I don't see any dispatching here, do you? @YuryTarabanko

Comment: Oh cmon. First `mapDispatchToProps` could be an object. Then OP doesn't need action creator to return a function (a thunk because his action creator dispatches single action and doesn't use current state). It seems you have no idea what are you suggesting to do.

Comment: You're obviously confusing `mapDispatchToProps` with `mapStateToProps`

Comment: No `({ forms }) => ({ forms })` this is `mapStateToProps`. `{ formInput }` this is `mapDispatchToProps` which **is perfectly ok to be an object**

Comment: I agree about that being a object. But but but but, he is not dispatching that object. Which is problem, unless, he creates a bound action creator like I defined above. https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html

Comment: This will be done by `connect` itself. If this line of code does not convince you I quit :) https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js#L18

Comment: @eden Go create a test app for your self and import your action from a file than put it as an object into connect a see what happens. It works perfectly as it should. It is dispatching the action. I don't se why you people arguing about it. Your solution works at this case **but don't understand why** the original approach with action object inside `connect` doesn't work.

Comment: Read again my question. I do give you credit for the answer because it solves the issue. But why the first version worked and when I import it from index why it now does not.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko okay that convinced me. sorry for misguiding guys.